# Creating an iterative function using lag and mutate command in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tapply

I have a data set DF with the following data

| Zone | Year | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2018 | 10 | 5 |
| 1001 | 2019 | 20 | 10 |
| 1001 | 2020 | 30 | 20 |
| 1002 | 2018 | 15 | 10 |
| 1002 | 2019 | 25 | 20 |
| 1002 | 2020 | 35 | 40 |

I want to create a column Z = X + Y - Previous year's Y
So it creates the following Table:

| Zone | Year | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2018 | 10 | 5 | NA |
| 1001 | 2019 | 20 | 10 | 25 |
| 1001 | 2020 | 30 | 20 | 40 |
| 1002 | 2018 | 15 | 10 | NA |
| 1002 | 2019 | 25 | 20 | 35 |
| 1002 | 2020 | 35 | 40 | 55 |

I can use "mutate" from DPLYR to generate column Z:
mutate(DF, Z = X + Y - lag(Y))

I can use tapply to apply recursively on DF. Can I create a function using DPLYR in a user-defined function to apply this using tapply later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` you can add `group_by` to apply a function for every group (`Zone`).

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(Zone) %>% mutate(Z = X + Y - lag(Y))

#   Zone  Year     X     Y     Z
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  1001  2018    10     5    NA
#2  1001  2019    20    10    25
#3  1001  2020    30    20    40
#4  1002  2018    15    10    NA
#5  1002  2019    25    20    35
#6  1002  2020    35    40    55
```

We can also write a function :

```
add_new_col = function(x, y) {
  x + y - lag(y)
}
```

which can be used as :

```
DF %>% group_by(Zone) %>% mutate(Z = add_new_col(X, Y))
```

**data**

```
DF <- structure(list(Zone = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L
), Year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L), X = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 15L, 25L, 35L), Y = c(5L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 40L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. This helps me understand DPLYR. I am looking at creating a general function that takes any data frame and variable name and returns a new column.

Comment: See my updated answer where I show how to apply function in this case. Maybe that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, Z := X + Y - shift(Y), Zone]
```